# Saving a .mat file in csv format

Tags: matlab, csv

I have a .mat file and the data structure is as below.

Data =

struct with fields:

```
        axis1: [25626600×1 double]
        axis2: [25626600×1 double]
        axis3: [25626600×1 double]
      datenum: [25626600×1 double]
  sample_rate: 30
serial_number: 'MOS2D10171145'
```

I want this .mat file to be save as a csv file.

I tried this code but it gives me this error.

`csvwrite('FileName.csv', Data);`

```
Undefined function 'real' for input arguments of type 'struct'.

Error in dlmwrite (line 189)
                    str = sprintf('%.*g%+.*gi',precn,real(m(i,j)),precn,imag(m(i,j)));

Error in csvwrite (line 42)
dlmwrite(filename, m, ',', r, c);
```

Comment: What do you expect the csv to look like, just a 2562600x4 table (without the `sample_rate`  or `serial_number` information)? Reading the documentation for `csvwrite` it expects a matrix input, you're giving it a struct, it's not well defined how you expect to convert from a struct to a "flat" csv format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as explained by Wolfie, you cannot do this direclty, because your **sample_rate** and your **serial_number** variables cannot go direclty in your CSV.

A solution could be to put these 2 variable in your CSV filename to keep them.

```
%% Parameters
cdSAVE='YOUR_PATH'; % PUT YOUR SAVING PATH

%% Variables (put your own)
axis1 = zeros(250,1);
axis2 = zeros(250,1)+1;
axis3 = zeros(250,1)+2;
datenum = zeros(250,1)+3;
sample_rate = 30;
serial_number = 'SERIAL_NUMBER';

%% Make a matrix with what you can
Matrix = zeros(length(axis1),4);
Matrix(:,1)=axis1;
Matrix(:,2)=axis2;
Matrix(:,3)=axis3;
Matrix(:,4)=datenum;

%% Convert to table (to have the headers written in your csv file)
T = array2table(Matrix);
T.Properties.VariableNames(1:4) = {'axis1','axis2','axis3','datenum'};

%% Create a the filename with the 2 other datas
fileName = char(strcat('Extract_CSV_Sample_rate_',string(sample_rate),'_Serial_Number_',serial_number,'.csv'));

%% Writing
fullPathFileName=char(strcat(cdSAVE,"\",fileName));

%% Choose what you want :

%% Here for just the matrix with csvwrite
csvwrite(fullPathFileName,Matrix);

%% Here with headers also with writetable
writetable(T,fullPathFileName)
```

And the CSV name will be : **Extract_CSV_Sample_rate_30_Serial_Number_SERIAL_NUMBER.csv**

Comment: You shouldn't need to keep casting to `char`, use `sprintf` or simple `['char', 'concatenation']` with `fullfile` to create the file name(s) instead. You can also set the var names within the call to `array2table` using `array2table( Matrix, 'VariableNames', {'a','b','c','d'} );`